# vim cannot open file when run from .vimrc, but can open fine when run from terminal

Tags: vim

Whenever I try to open any file with Vim I get this error message:

```
Error detected while processing /home/emma/.vimrc:
line  138:
E484: Can't open file '/home/emma/.opam/system/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But the strange thing is that when I do this, the file actually opens:

```
vim ~/.opam/system/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim
```

So I've verified that the file does exist and that Vim is capable of displaying the code.

Here are lines 120 to the end of my `.vimrc`:
[image]

And here is the entirety of `~/.opam/system/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim`:
[image]

Comment: my blind friends thank you @melpomene

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When vim says

```
E484: Can't open file '/home/emma/.opam/system/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim'
```

it literally means a file called,

`'/home/emma/.opam/system/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim'`

not

`/home/emma/.opam/system/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim`

In other words, the problem is the quotes you added around the filename.

Fix:

```
  source /home/emma/.opam/system/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim
```

Also, you could use `~` there:

```
  source ~/.opam/system/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim
```